# How can I access the return value from twisted deferred callbacks using AsyncioSelectorReactor?

Tags: scrapy, python-asyncio, twisted

Using Python 3.7.7, Twisted 20.3.0 (and Scrapy 2.1.0), when I try...

```
doc_link = await self.upload_reseller_document(doc_request, self.create_id(contract))
```

I get a deferred instead of a string. Also my callbacks are not awaited.

Expected: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/some-bucket/some_file.csv` or `None`

Received: `<Deferred at 0x11ae61dd0 current result: None>`

```
    async def conditional_upload(request):
        docs_bucket = 'some-bucket'
        key = f'some-prefix/some_file.csv'
        url = f'https://s3.amazonaws.com/{docs_bucket}/{key}'
        async def cb(obj):
            print('found key, returning url')
            return defer.success(url)

        async def upload_doc():
            print('called upload_doc')
            response = await self.crawler.engine.download(request, self)
            if response.status != 200:
                # Error happened, return item.
                print('could not download reseller csv')
                return defer.error(None)
            print('uploading to', docs_bucket, key)
            return threads.deferToThread(
                self.s3client.put_object,
                Bucket=docs_bucket,
                Key=key,
                Body=response.body)

        async def eb(failure):
            print('did not find key')
            if failure.type != ClientError:
                raise failure.value
            return upload_doc()

        return ensureDeferred(threads.deferToThread(
                self.s3client.head_object,
                Bucket=docs_bucket,
                Key=key).addCallbacks(cb, eb))
```

Comment: You _are_ returning the result of a function called `ensureDeferred`, whose job is to convert its argument to a Deferred. This is why you're getting a Deferred out of the function. Try `return await ensureDeferred(...)`.

Comment: Also, if you have `await` at your disposal, you probably don't need to go through `addCallbacks` in the first place, you can just await the result of deferToThread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally Twisted deals only with Deferreds and functions that returns it, you can't pass `async` functions as callbacks to Deferreds (when called, async functions returns a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) object), if you do, the callback will have no effect and at the reactor stop you will get a warning "coroutine x was never awaited".
When using async functions, you should just [await](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html#coroutines-with-async-await) the Deferreds finish and handle their result instead of appending callbacks and returning them. The goal of async functions is to avoid the [callback hell](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/callback_hell).

[defer.ensureDeferred](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.ensureDeferred.html) is used to wrap coroutines in a deferred and allow Twisted to schedule them to be ran, you use it when you need to call async functions inside functions that are not async.

Use try/catch to handle the exceptions (it's equivalent to `errback`, but the exception is not wrapped in twisted's `Failure`):

```py
async def conditional_upload(request):
    docs_bucket = 'some-bucket'
    key = f'some-prefix/some_file.csv'
    url = f'https://s3.amazonaws.com/{docs_bucket}/{key}'

    async def upload_doc():
        print('called upload_doc')
        response = await self.crawler.engine.download(request, self)
        if response.status != 200:
            # Error happened, return item.
            print('could not download reseller csv')
            raise Exception('could not download reseller csv')
        print('uploading to', docs_bucket, key)
        return await threads.deferToThread(
            self.s3client.put_object, Bucket=docs_bucket, Key=key, Body=body
        )

    # propably here you want to check if something already exists
    try:
        await threads.deferToThread(self.s3client.head_object, Bucket=docs_bucket, Key=key)
        print('found key, returning url')
        return url
    except ClientError:
        print('did not find key, going to upload_doc ...')

    # if does not exists, then create it
    retry_attempts = 10 # avoid infinite loop
    for _ in range(retry_attempts):
        try:
            await upload_doc()
            print('Uploaded the key, returning url')
            return url
        except ClientError:
            print('Failed to upload the key, retrying...')

    print('Failed to upload the key, max attemps tried.')
```